# Is there a way to ensure performUpkeep isn't called again before it finishes performing work?

Tags: chainlink

I have a keeper that calls checkUpkeep and it returns true, however in performUpkeep, the condition that would cause checkUpkeep to return false is not set until data is returned from offchain (this is bc I want to make sure that if for some reason that fails, the checkUpkeep will return true again to retry)

How would I handle this so that checkUpkeep is not called again while data is being retrieved triggering a second performUpkeep?

ex:

```
  function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData)
    external
    view
    returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData)
  {
    require(revealed);
    require(round < 7);
    uint32 secondsInDay = 86_400;

    _getDateBeforeTimestamp(block.timestamp) >= latestDateChecked + secondsInDay
        ? upkeepNeeded = true
        : upkeepNeeded = false;
    performData = checkData;
  }

  function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external {
    requestVolumeData(); // latestDateChecked is updated once requestVolumeData successfully receives data offchain and calls fulfill function
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if what you are concerned about is possible.

In the EVM a transaction either succeeds or fails. There is no waiting or async. Or maybe there's some chainlink magic (involving transactions that do not occur in the same block) happening that I have not learned about yet.

My suggestion: use blocknumber (block.number) to create an aditional entry condition. That's what I'm using for a keeper to call a function approx. once a day.

```
    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData)
    external
    view
    returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData)
  {
    require(revealed);
    require(round < 7);
    **require(block.number >= lastUpkeepBlock + 10 )** //if you can afford artificial constraint

    uint32 secondsInDay = 86_400;

    _getDateBeforeTimestamp(block.timestamp) >= latestDateChecked + secondsInDay
        ? upkeepNeeded = true
        : upkeepNeeded = false;
    performData = checkData;
    
    **uint lastUpkeepBlock = block.number;**
    
  }

  function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external {
    requestVolumeData(); // latestDateChecked is updated once requestVolumeData successfully receives data offchain and calls fulfill function
  }
```

or OpenZeppelin's [nonReentrant](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/security#ReentrancyGuard) modifier.

Related Concepts:
[Reentrancy](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-107)
[Race condition](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-114)